# Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2

Tags: python, macos, pip, psycopg2

I am new to python. I am trying to execute my project but I am encountering some sort of error which is mentioned below while doing `pip install -r requirements-local.txt`

I created virtual environment using `virtualenv -p python3 venv` and activated it using `source venv/bin/activate` command. Then I try to install dependancy using `pip install -r requirements-local.txt` which throws error

Some part of the error :

````
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error

and 

Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/akshaysalekar/Documents/Projects/lambda-patch-ats/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/cy/cgz3qm196wg_h0wfdgh4clkr0000gn/T/pip-install-zss21x7x/psycopg2_0948f735c8ed42f6b38b42db053c4168/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/cy/cgz3qm196wg_h0wfdgh4clkr0000gn/T/pip-install-zss21x7x/psycopg2_0948f735c8ed42f6b38b42db053c4168/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/cy/cgz3qm196wg_h0wfdgh4clkr0000gn/T/pip-record-cmz8fx78/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/akshaysalekar/Documents/Projects/lambda-patch-ats/venv/include/site/python3.9/psycopg2
         cwd: /private/var/folders/cy/cgz3qm196wg_h0wfdgh4clkr0000gn/T/pip-install-zss21x7x/psycopg2_0948f735c8ed42f6b38b42db053c4168/
    Complete output (141 lines):```
````

I am using Macbook pro (macOS Big Sur). My python version is `3.9.6` , pip verison is `pip 21.2.2`.

My requirement file has only two dependencies which are

```
psycopg2==2.7.7 
boto3==1.9.100
```

I have tried upgrading outdated package, Installing wheel package and reinstalling python and updating pip but no luck.
Can someone please help me in this.
Thank you

Edit : The complete error message is pasted here;
https://pastebin.com/raw/M9viR8fU

Comment: Well the latest `psycopg2` version is 2.9.1. From 2.7.x to 2.8.x there a change in binary packaging, see here [Binary](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#change-in-binary-packages-between-psycopg-2-7-and-2-8).  I would try the latest version or the changes shown in the link(though that will require -dev packages for the compile). It would also help to update the question with the part of the error message that reveals more. I'm guessing it will be towards the end of the message.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for the reply. I have alreadt tried the solution that you have provided but its alreadt updated. States "Requirement already satisfied:" . I have added link for complete error message . Thank  you

Comment: Well if you got "Requirement already satisfied:" then `psycopg2` is already installed. Though it is hard to tell since you left off the import part of the message. You need to get in the habit of including complete messages. In any case does `pip freeze` show `psycopg2` installed and if so what version?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 
yes ```pip freez``` shows ```psycopg2==2.9.1```

Following is the result I got from pip freeze 
```boto3==1.9.100
botocore==1.12.253
certifi==2021.5.30
chardet==3.0.4
charset-normalizer==2.0.4
docutils==0.15.2
idna==2.8
jmespath==0.10.0
psycopg2==2.9.1
psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
python-dateutil==2.8.2
requests==2.22.0
s3transfer==0.2.1
six==1.16.0
urllib3==1.25.11
```

Comment: So it is installed, you should be good to go.